# Website is not loading in chrome and firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, magento, firefox, ssl-certificate

My magento website is not loading in chrome and firefox.It works fine in IE only. I cleared the chrome cache and history but it not display my website it shows like "This webpage is not available  ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH ". How to solve this error i am working on this issue for last 2 days.

Comment: Your server is using either an old (and known vulnerable) SSL version or/and only serves with old (and known vulnerable) ciphers. This has nothing to do with the browsers and everything with your server configuration.

Comment: Bad server configuration or outdated software. Contact your service provider or arrange for server maintenance to bring your security up to modern levels. This question is more appropriate for superuser or serverfault

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing to do with your website as such, that's a server configuration issue.

Most likely your server is still trying to serve https requests using SSL3, which has been removed in Chrome 40 (and I guess firefox as well, but I don't have the changelogs to hand to check)

This is a good tool to check your SSL settings:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

This will confirm any issues, and advise on fixes.

If you don't have full server access, then you'll need to speak to your host.